# Android intent to open Word with intent's text in a new document

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send data from my android app to Office Mobile (particularly Word Document) android app. What value should I supply at the `setType()` method below, the current value does not bring Office Mobile among options. It just brings twitter, facebook, etc.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I setup an android intent for multiple types of files (pdf, office, images, text) and return a path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367272/how-can-i-setup-an-android-intent-for-multiple-types-of-files-pdf-office-imag)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Opening a Word document using intents and FileProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54836448/android-opening-a-word-document-using-intents-and-fileprovider)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public static void openFile(Context context, File url) throws IOException {
    // Create URI
    File file=url;
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    if(url.toString().contains(".docx")) {
        // Text file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
}

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

Some other links in case this doesn't work: [Android how to open a .doc extension file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242306/android-how-to-open-a-doc-extention-file)
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Hope it works! Good Luck! Happy Coding!