# Intent ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT: browse multiple MIME type

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types

I have this intent for let user choose images:

```
 fun launchChooseFileIntent(callerFragment: BaseFragment, REQUEST_CODE: Int) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "image/*,"
    }

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

Now i need that user can choose both images and pdf documents.
I've try to change **type** string like

```
type = "image/*,application/pdf"
```

or like

```
type = "image/*|application/pdf"
```

but it doesn't work.

I've try also to add extra to intent like

```
putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayOf("image/*", "application/pdf"))
```

but the app crash.

How can i solve it?

Comment: "the app crash" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 6):

Answer on your question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367272/how-can-i-setup-an-android-intent-for-multiple-types-of-files-pdf-office-imag)

Here is my sample code, tested in api 28.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            String[] mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "text/csv", "text/plain"};
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, dialogTitle), requestCode);
```