# Getting pdf or doc file from Downloads Folder in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying numerous ways to open the Downloads folder of the user and allowing the user to ONLY select a doc or pdf file to open up. Majority of the methods out there have been deprecated and their alternatives just don't seem to work for me.

Current Code:

```
// I've heavily altered the code but hope you guys understand the gist of it.


//Steps:
// Open the Downloads folder 
// Let user select the pdf or docx.
// Open the doc or pdf.

        // Adding Syllabus Function Method Here.
        addSyllabus = findViewById(R.id.add_syllabus_button);
        addSyllabus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                String filename = "https://s25.q4cdn.com/967830246/files/doc_downloads/test.pdf";
                webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);
                webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        // do your stuff here
                        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

Appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: `ways to open the Downloads folder of the user and allowing the user to ONLY select a doc or pdf file to open up.`  The code you posted has nothing to do with this. Or with the subject of your post.

Comment: @blackapps I went through several iterations of this section and just pasted whatever I had currently. Hence why I said if you understand the gist of what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Intent` from [DocumentsProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider) is probably your best bet.

From this [Google Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#open-file):

```
private void openFile(Uri pickerInitialUri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");

    // Optionally, specify a URI for the file that should appear in the
    // system file picker when it loads.
    intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri);

    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PDF_FILE);
```

You can use `setType` as shown and if you want to default to Downloads, you can use `putExtra` as shown. Change `pickerInitialUri` to the correct URI, which I think can be found as a constant: [`Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment).

Update: I realize now you wanted more than one filetype. Per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367272/how-can-i-setup-an-android-intent-for-multiple-types-of-files-pdf-office-imag/27367413):
you can use:

```
String [] mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/msword", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"};
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
```

(I got the MIME type strings from [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types).)

Comment: What should I exactly pass into the parameter?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure which parameter you are talking about. for the `putExtra` call, you should probably change the second parameter to `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`, but I haven't tested it myself. Also, you're going to need certain permissions, but I'll direct you to other threads for that; there are plenty. See my edit if you need more clarification on the `setType`.